# Transfer specific datatable contents to another array

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, datatable

I'm trying to transfer my datatable contents to another array. I am only going to get specific  fields from the datatable, but I do not know how to save the specific columns content to another array.

What I did:

```
        dr = SuperViewBLL.GetSomeStuff();
        string[] new_array; 
        if (dr.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < dr.Rows.Count;i++ )
            {
               new_array[i] = dr.Rows[i]['StuffLocationId'];
               // I do know this is wrong
            }
        }
```

How can I get the column `StuffLocationId` to the array new_array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line is almost right, except that you need double quotes rather than single and you also need to cast/convert the value to type `String` to put it into a `String` array:

```
new_array[i] = (string) dr.Rows[i]["StuffLocationId"];
```

or, if the data is nullable:

```
new_array[i] = dr.Rows[i]["StuffLocationId"] as string;
```

The issue is that the array doesn't exist because you haven't created it.  In order to create an array you have to know the size.  If you haven't specified a size, either implicitly or explicitly, then you haven't created an array.  This:

```
string[] new_array;
```

should be this:

```
string[] new_array = new string[dr.Rows.Count - 1];
```

You can also throw a bit of LINQ at the problem and succinctify the code a bit:

```
var new_array = dr.AsEnumerable()
                  .Select(row => row["StuffLocationId"] as string)
                  .ToArray();
```

That's also an example of specifying the size of the array implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

This way is much more clear:

```
    dt = SuperViewBLL.GetSomeStuff();
    List<string> list = new List<string>();

    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        list.Add((!row.IsNull("StuffLocationId") ? row["StuffLocationId"] as string : string.Empty));
    }
```

Updated with the help of @jmcilhinney

Comment: While `ToString` is not necessarily wrong, I would say that, more often than not, a cast would be more appropriate.  If the data is already `String`s then there's no actual conversion to be done and if it's not then it probably shouldn't be going into a `String` array.  Also, if the data is nullable then using `ToString` will turn `DBNull.Value` into `String.Empty` instead of `null`, which might be desirable but probably shouldn't be in most cases.  If the data is nullable then a conditional cast is probably the most appropriate in most cases: `dr.Rows[i]["StuffLocationId"] as string`

Comment: If the data is nullable then you need to look for `DBNull.Value`, not `null`. There's no point using a ternary operator. If you want to use an empty `String` for database NULLs then just use `row["StuffLocationId"].ToString()` and it will handle that for you. If you want to use C# `null` for database nulls then use `row["StuffLocationId"] as string`.  Both quite succinct.  If you really did want to use a ternary operator then the most correct option would be `row.IsNull("StuffLocationId") ? string.Empty : (string) row["StuffLocationId"]` or `row.Field<string>("StuffLocationId")` for no cast.

Comment: I had this `row["StuffLocationId"].ToString()` tested already but it throws an error if the value is null. It doesn't handle that itself. but I like the idea of row.IsNull("xx"). thanks for that.

Comment: It DOES handle that itself if the field contains `DBNull.Value`, which it will if NULL data is retrieved from a database.  Database nulls are represented by `DBNull.Value`, which is an instance of the `DBNull` class, i.e. an object, rather than by `null`, which represents no object in C#.  It's that way because .NET did not originally support nullable value types so NULL data retrieved from a column containing integers or the like could not be represented with `null`.  The `ToString` method of the `DBNull` class returns `String.Empty`.